# Translucent StatusBar on kitkat with FrameLayout above the Toolbar and using CoordinatorLayout

Tags: android, android-4.4-kitkat, android-coordinatorlayout, android-statusbar

I was trying to achieve `Translucent StatusBar` on `kitkat` with the following `FrameLayout` and it's working **without** `CoordinatorLayout` like this:

**Layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/statusbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And this line in `Styles.xml-v19` of course:

```
<item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
```

And of course in the `onCreate`:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 19) {

            FrameLayout statusbar = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.statusbar);
            statusbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
```

And that worked:

[image]

But, i'm wondering how we can achieve that with `CoordinatorLayout` and `AppbarLayout`?

**Here is my try by the way:**

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

            <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:id="@+id/toolbarCollapse"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

                <FrameLayout
                    android:id="@+id/statusbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="25dp"
                    android:background="?attr/colorPrimaryDark" />

                    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                        android:id="@+id/toolbarmain"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                        android:background="@color/ColorPrimary"
                        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
                        app:popupTheme="@style/ToolbarStylepopuptheme"
                        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />


            </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
                app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/white"
                app:tabIndicatorHeight="2dp"
                app:tabMode="scrollable" />

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

And didn't work.

**Update:** Also this one is not working:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".ui.MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/statusBar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:translationZ="8dp" />

        <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
            android:id="@+id/root_coordinator"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
                android:id="@+id/nestedscrollview"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

...
...
```

Any solutions to achieve that?

Something like [ADM app on GooglePlay](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dv.adm&hl=en) design.

Also, let's mention that, i've had the same problem with [SystemBarTint](https://github.com/jgilfelt/SystemBarTint) when i was using `CoordinatorLayout`(same condition).

I couldn't figured out how they could do that.

Also, there is a good tutorial here, https://youtu.be/YCThIedqbCQ but it doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 1):

Can you not just do this? It seems like you're moving your faux status bar into the Coordinator layout when you don't need to?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="1">

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/statusbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="25dp"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />

<Coordinator>
    <AppBarLayout>
        <CollapsibleToolbarLayout>
            <Toolbar/>
        </CollapsibleToolbarLayout>
    </AppBarLayout>
    <NestedScrollView/>
</Coordinator>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Wrap it inside `FrameLayout`, so the statusbar `FrameLayout` gets on top and everything slides beneath it.

Comment: This totally misses the point of fitsSystemWindows ... but considering how extremely broken it is, I wouldn't blame anyone using this workaround.

Comment: @Su-AuHwang - So, what is your suggestion?

Comment: @Mohsen I simply decided not have a translucent statusbar for API < 21. The above solution works for some cases (but not for parallax image behind it). In the end, it's a nice little extra to have a little bit more immersion, but it might break it for certain devices, e.g. when a manufacturer decides to implement a mode for ppl with bad vision and now the status bar is 50 dp. All in all, I don't think it's worth it, but that's up to you to decide for your usecase.