# Android - Change status bar color on pre-lollipop devices programatically

Tags: android, material-design, statusbar

I want to change the status bar colour  on pre-lollipop devices programmatically. I am well aware the material design colouPrimaryDark wont work on pre-lollipop as status bar colour is concern of OS itself which pre-lollipop devices wont provide such feature. So I want to do it programmatically through java file. Is that possible?

currently I am using this material design code.

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>
<style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primaryColor</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primaryColor</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/primaryColor</item>
</style>
```

As this wont work with API below 21. So I want to do it through java.

Comment: I don't think that's possible.

Comment: its possible there are many application in market which does that .. like whatsapp for example

Comment: @Yash Singh: I have pre lollipop deveice and Whats app status bar colour is Black.

Comment: See this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/26215844/5235032

Comment: Thanks folks maybe I was wrong, in pre-lollipop it was not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, we can use that on + `KitKat`.

**Check this link:** http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#windowTranslucentStatus

> - Has been added in `API level 19` which means, there is a way to do    that.check my blog about using it with [`SystemTintBar`](https://github.com/jgilfelt/SystemBarTint):
>        https://linx64.ir/blog/2016/02/05/translucent-statusbar-on-kitkat/
> - And this is the another method(without using `CoordinatorLayout`):    [Translucent StatusBar on kitkat with FrameLayout above the Toolbar and using CoordinatorLayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35222550/translucent-statusbar-on-kitkat-with-framelayout-above-the-toolbar-and-using-coo)

Just add this to the top of your layout:

```
<FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/statusbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />
```

And use this:

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT == 19) {

            FrameLayout statusbar = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.statusbar);
            statusbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
```

It should work on `Kitkat`, and like i said, this is also available only for + `Kitkat`.

Comment: It's 24dp on Marshmallow.

Comment: It works on API 17. But we can not use the "scroll down to see notifications", as in general status bar. I also used  activity.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        activity.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

Answer (score 0):

Simply its not possible it the matter of the os itself to manage those things. pre-lollipop android versions won't gave such privilege to change status bar colour.